# MySQL query for getting blog records/content Drupal7?

Tags: views

I want to customize the and limit the content from the blog entry. If I want hook the sql query output for blog entry, How can i do it?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit is controlled through a variable called `default_nodes_main`. You can change it by executing the following code:

```
// This would increase the number of nodes on the blog page to 20.
variable_set('default_nodes_main', 20);
```

If you have [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module installed, you can do this at `/devel/php`.

Comment: Thanks. But is there any way to control the default sql query for blog entries?

Comment: You can use `hook_menu_alter()` and re-create those pages in your custom module. That way you can edit the queries any way you want. I think you can't alter the query without this, because there are no tags added to it. If you want, I can update my answer above with a sample `hook_menu_alter()` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by 'limit the content' of the blog entries but there's a module that limits amount of content (number of chars) on a text field already. That maybe what you're after.

https://www.drupal.org/project/maxlength